# How to tell Siri Remote button presses and gamepad button presses apart?

Tags: swift, tvos, apple-tv, gamepad, siri-remote

I wrote an override for `pressesBegan(_ presses: Set<UIPress>, with event: UIPressesEvent?)` on my ViewController.

```swift
  open override func pressesBegan(_ presses: Set<UIPress>, with event: UIPressesEvent?) {
    #if os(tvOS)
    for press in presses {
      switch press.type {
      case .menu: print("menu"); break;
      case .select: print("select"); break;
      case .playPause: print("playPause"); break;
      default: break;
      }
    }
    #endif
  }
```

It correctly sees a `UIPress` that has `press.type` set to `.menu` when I press the “menu” button on the Siri Remote.

However, it *also* gets a `.menu` press event when I press “circle” (`buttonB`) on a DualShock 4 gamepad that I've connected to my Apple TV. Is this normal? Is it documented behavior? (I assume the idea is to make apps “automatically” navigable with a gamepad.)

I don't always want “B on the gamepad” and “MENU on the remote” to do the same thing. How can I tell these two cases apart? Neither `UIPressesEvent` nor `UIPress` seem to carry any information in their fields as to which device originated the keypress. Is there some other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing my ViewController situation around so that I present a [GCEventViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/gamecontroller/gceventviewcontroller) whenever I don't want the B button to perform navigation. Then I use the tools offered by `GameController` to handle gamepad presses and `pressesBegan` seems to no longer be triggered by the B button.